# Facebook Open Graph with multiple images - doesn't seem to work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

What's the trick with Open Graph tags to get Facebook to let you to choose from a list of thumbnails?

Facebook auto-chooses the first image I output in my og tags and doesn't give me the ability to choose a second (or third, etc) from the post. The "Choose a thumbnail" control is not enabled and says 1 of 1.

[image]

When I debug the page using the Facebook debugger, it successfully shows me all the images and doesn't report any errors.

As an example, here are my og tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Page Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Page Description">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.test.com/index.cfm"> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.test.com/images/og-3.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.test.com/images/og-4.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<img src="image.jpg" />` in your object page's `<body>` for each of your images.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question... I'm asking about using Open Graph tags to tell Facebook which images to use. If you don't know what Open Graph is, you should probably get yourself up to speed! :)